# Scaling SVG Button Mask in ChakraUI

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, scale, chakra-ui

I am trying to create a specially shaped button that overlays a section of an image and am running into issues with the scaling of the button mask.
The image and the masks were created together and are both the exact same base dimensions for easy aligning at 0,0.

I have a simple working version in plain HTML:

```css
#imageContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.shapedButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  clip-path: url(#mask);
}

.shapedButton:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="imageContainer">
    <img src="image.png">
    <button class="shapedButton"></button>
  </div>
</body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="mask">
        <path fill="#000000" opacity="1.000000" stroke="none" d="Omitted for better readability"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>

</html>
```

However, I am running into issues with getting a similar result in React (specifically NextJS + Chakra):

```html
import { Button, Container, Image } from "@chakra-ui/react";
const LoadMask = (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="mask">
        <path d="Omitted for better readability"
        />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
);

export function InteractiveImage() { return (
<Container position="relative" maxW="7199px" w="80%" p={0}>
  <Image src="image.png" />
  <Button
    position="absolute"
    top="0"
    left="0"
    w="100%"
    h="100%"
    p="0"
    cursor="pointer"
    background="rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
    clipPath="url(#mask)"
    _hover={{ background: "transparent", }}
   >
   {LoadMask}
   </Button>
</Container>
); }
```

The mask display and functionality works as intended, but the mask itself is currently too large and overflows the container and I can't seem to get the mask to properly scale to fit its container through any means. The svg element itself is perfectly contained, but rather the visual part of the clippath overflows.

I have attempted to edit the width, height, viewBox, and maintainAspectRatio to fix this, however the scale of the mask responds to none of these. The only thing that scales the mask at all is the in-browser zoom. My best guess is that it is scaling to the vw of the page rather than the container it is inside, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: You probably ought to use objectBoundingBox units for your clipPath

Answer (score 0):

Robert was correct in the direction to head.
Converting the SVG to a 1x1 scale and setting the clipPath attribute `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` solved the scaling issues entirely.